# ChangingTikz Node Style works only once in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I am trying to change the node style of a Tikz-node twice in Beamer but the second time the change is not done. What needs to be fixed in my MWE to make it work?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=fooFrame]{You Will Be Amazed.}
\tikzstyle{empty} = [shape=rectangle, draw=green, fill=green, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm]
\tikzstyle{wip} = [shape=rectangle, draw=red, fill=red, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm, label={center:?}]
\tikzstyle{done} = [shape=rectangle, thick, draw=blue!50, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm, label={center:$\checkmark$}]

\tikzstyle{mynode} = [empty]
\only<2>{\tikzset{mynode/.style={wip}}}
\only<3>{\tikzset{mynode./style={done}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is that the style `empty` is applied on the first slide, the style `wip` in the second slide but then `empty` is applied again in the last slide, where I would expect `done` to appear.

Note:

1. Also I could not replace the use of `\tikzstyle{}` with `\tikzset` on the first slide.
2. Using `\only<1>{...}` also doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little syntax error. You have

```
\only<3>{\tikzset{mynode./style={done}}}
```

and it should be

```
\only<3>{\tikzset{mynode/.style={done}}}
```

(the dot *after* the slash).

The complete code (I changed the old syntax `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
empty/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw=green, fill=green, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm},
wip/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw=red, fill=red, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm, label={center:?}},
done/.style = {shape=rectangle, thick, draw=blue!50, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4mm, label={center:$\checkmark$}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=fooFrame]{You Will Be Amazed.}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={empty}}
\only<2>{\tikzset{mynode/.style={wip}}}
\only<3>{\tikzset{mynode/.style={done}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]